# How to fit and forecast time series with value boundary?

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

[ratio time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSsNo.png)

My time series time need to be fit is a ratio, it's value should be between [0,1]

If I fit it directly with mstl+forecast, auto arima with Fourier or tbats, the module didn't know this prior and will give forecast beyond ONE. And the value of the forecast seems to be pull up. 
Like this: [mstl+forecast](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R46FX.png)

Here is part of my code:

```
msts_y <- msts(df[,'y'], seasonal.periods = c(24, 7*24))
msts_y %>% mstl()-> msts_y.mstl.fit
msts_y.mstl.fc<-forecast(msts_y.mstl.fit, h=7*24)
autoplot(msts_y.mstl.fc)
```

Comment: See https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/forecasting-within-limits/

Comment: Thanks!   I just finished your book fpp2, it's very helpful!

Comment: My data has already reached the boundary 1, I tried to add a esp=0.001 in the logistic denominator,  but the fitted value is bad when data is noisy, what I should do? Thanks!